# Rewrite rule regexp

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to ask you guys because I have a problem with one my rewrite rules and I can't figure it out how to write the good one. 
I have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*[^(.js|.swf)])$ authenticate.php?file=$1
```

What I would like to do is redirect the user to the `authenticate.php` every time when someone tries to open something in the `wp-content` uploads dir and I would like to send the filename to the php

For example:

```
http://domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/something.pdf
```

redirect to `authenticate.php?file=something.pdf`

But unfortunately my regexp is broken. Could someone help me?

Really thanks for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with that in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:js|swf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.+)$ authenticate.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```

For `http://domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/something.pdf` the result:  `http://domain.tld/authenticate.php?file=2015/11/something.pdf`

Comment: If you do not want `/2015/11/`, specify whether the format is always present and always in the format `/YYYY/MM/`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex with negative lookaheads:

```
^.*?wp-content\/uploads\/.*?\.(?!js$|swf$)[^.]+$
```

The following URL will match the regex:

```
http://cpsma.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/CPSMA-Newsletter-No-35-Sept-2015-2.pdf
```

However, a similar URL which ends in `.js` or `.swf` will *not* match.  Hence, the following two URLs do *not* match the regex:

```
http://domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/javascript.js
http://domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/shockwavefile.swf
```

You can test this regex out here:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/yH6dZ8/3)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. I tried it out but unfortunately it's not working. 
Here is the link 

http://cpsma.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/CPSMA-Newsletter-No-35-Sept-2015-2.pdf

But it shows the pdf content.

Here is the htaccess
[code]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^http.*?wp-content\/uploads\/.*?\.(?!js$|swf$)[^.]+$ auth.php?file=$1

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
[/code]

Comment: I updated my answer.  I assumed that all your URLs will start with `http` but apparently this is not the case.

Comment: I think something with the redirect not working because It's not triggered at all. Your regexp is fine, but any time when I call the page nothing happens. :/

    RewriteRule ^.*?wp-content\/uploads\/.*?\.(?!js$|swf$)[^.]+$ auth.php?file=$1